# Moving text to new line with fetching data from firebase

Tags: css, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a website that shows results from firebase.
I'm displaying data in a table, and showing the data in td tags.
Here's how I fetch my data:

```
var database = firebase.database();

      database.ref('box-label').once('value', function(snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
          var content = '';
          snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
            var val = data.val();
            content += '<td>' + val.brand + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + val.style + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + val.color + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + val.ponumber + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + val.color + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + val.xs + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + val.sm + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + val.md + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + val.lg + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + val.xl + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + val.xxl + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + val.xxxl + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + val.onesize + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + val.ponumber + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + val.totalunits + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + val.boxnumber + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + val.totalboxes + '</td>';
            content += '<td> ' + val.boxweight + '</td>';

          });
          $('#the__carton__results').append(content);
        }
      });
```

This works out well, with one entry from the firebase, however if there's more than one firebase entry, the layout breaks.
For example: This is with 2 entries [image: Entries]
The first entry ends with Mikk7, and I'd like to show the next entries on the next line, so it aligns right.

My styling for the table looks like this:

```
  tr#the__carton__results__table{
      font-size: 9px;
      font-weight: 900;
      font-family: Helvetica;
      text-align: center;
  }

  tr#the__carton__results{
      font-size: 9px;
      font-weight: 900;
      font-family: Helvetica;
      text-align: center;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're constantly adding cells to the same row in the table. So that means you end up with a single row for all products.

What you probably want is to generate a new row for each product:

```
var database = firebase.database();

database.ref('box-label').once('value', function(snapshot) {
  var content = '';
  snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
    content += '<tr>';
    var val = data.val();
    content += '<td>' + val.brand + '</td>';
    content += '<td>' + val.style + '</td>';
    content += '<td>' + val.color + '</td>';
    content += '<td>' + val.ponumber + '</td>';
    content += '<td>' + val.color + '</td>';
    content += '<td>' + val.xs + '</td>';
    content += '<td>' + val.sm + '</td>';
    content += '<td>' + val.md + '</td>';
    content += '<td>' + val.lg + '</td>';
    content += '<td>' + val.xl + '</td>';
    content += '<td>' + val.xxl + '</td>';
    content += '<td>' + val.xxxl + '</td>';
    content += '<td>' + val.onesize + '</td>';
    content += '<td>' + val.ponumber + '</td>';
    content += '<td>' + val.totalunits + '</td>';
    content += '<td>' + val.boxnumber + '</td>';
    content += '<td>' + val.totalboxes + '</td>';
    content += '<td> ' + val.boxweight + '</td>';
    content += '</tr>';

  });
  $('#the__carton__results').parent().append(content);
});
```

Comment: Shame how I missed  that simple thing, Thanks Frank!